# Adjective for fried food

Tags: selección-de-palabras, adjetivos, comida

## Español

El día de ayer estuve discutiendo con un amigo sobre como llamar a las comidas que estan fritas. ¿Llamas al pollo "frito" o "freido"?

> El pollo está **frito**
>
> El pollo está **freido**

Para mi, "frito" es la forma correcta pero según Google Translate "freido" es una traducción poco común:

[image]

Toda mi vida he estado seguro de que el adjetivo "freido" ni siquiera existía hasta ahora. ¿Es correcto usar "freido"? No suena correcto desde mi punto de vista

---

## English

So yesterday I was arguing with a friend about how fried food should be called.  You call a fried chicken "frito" or "freido"?:

> El pollo está **frito**
>
> El pollo está **freido**

For me, "frito" was the way to go but according to Google Translate "freido" it's a rare translation:

[image]

My whole life I've been pretty sure that the adjective "freido" didn't even exist until now. Is it okay to use "freido"? It just doesn't sound correct to me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hay que tener cuidado en no confundir el *adjetivo* con el *participio pasivo*.

En el ejemplo de las *frituras* (que es como se le denomina genéricamente a las cosas que han sido freídas) podemos construir una frase que contenga ambos elementos, haciendo uso de la oración dada en la pregunta original:

> El pollo está *frito* después de haber sido *freído* en aceite.

- La primera palabra (*frito*) es un adjetivo, que corresponde al atributo en la oración copulativa.
- La segunda palabra (*freído*)<sup>1</sup> es un participio pasivo, como parte de la voz pasiva que complementa a la oración principal.

Cuando es adjetivo, solamente podemos usar *frito*. Sin embargo, cuando es participio pasivo, podemos usar tanto *frito* como *freído*.

---

<sup>1</sup> Ojo, que tal como dice @SergioRomero, la segunda palabra también puede ser *frito*.

Answer (score 3):

I am actually shocked but according to [RAE](http://dle.rae.es/freir) it seems that "freído" is actually accepted. (To see it, click on the link for the definition and then the "conj" button to see its conjugation. At the top in the middle is the "Participio" and both forms are displayed.)

After a short [Google search and a few hits in Yahoo answers](http://www.bing.com/search?setmkt=en-US&q=fre%C3%ADr%20fre%C3%ADdo) and other language forums it seems that there are three verbs that accept a double Past Participle (since these sites are not official, take it with a grain of salt):

> Imprimir: imprimido/impreso
>   Proveer: proveído/provisto
>   Freír: freído/frito

As far as I am concerned "frito" is the way to go, especially since it is the way I know most people say it so, even though "freído" is apparently correct, it is very likely that you will get "odd faces" if you say it like that.

Comment: Te comento lo mismo que en la pregunta, si es posible traduce tu respuesta ya que prefiremos el español en el sitio :)

Comment: Imprimido, freido and proveido, all sound SO bad in my ears ...:P

Comment: @belisarius: I hear you. Don't tell me, tell RAE.

Comment: And they are so picky most of the time ...

Answer (score 1):

Although "freido" is valid, it is rarely used. "frito" is generally accepted by the majority of the Spanish-speaking population.